# More info from ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, iis, threadabortexception

We have an IIS-hosted WCF service that receives a large chunk of data to work on. The service fires up several worker threads and then returns leaving the worker threads to finish the job (which might take an hour). If the WCF service is idle long enough IIS recycles tha app pool aborting the worker threads. This problem has been circumvented by having the worker threads occasionally call a dummy service just to keep the app pool alive. If you think this whole setup is a really bad idea, I completely agree (not my code). So no need to comment that.

The problem is we still get an occasional ThreadAbortException. **Is there any way to get additional information about what/who initiated the thread abort?** I know it isn't our code.

Comment: Maybe looking at the call stack that is included in the exception?

Comment: Uwe, call stack is pretty random, as I would expect if the abort is initiated by an outside process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS logs turned out to give the answer. AFAIK, if new binariers are loaded IIS waits until all service calls are finished (and no new call are accepted), then recycles the app pool. However, IIs has no knowledge of the background threads running after the service and therefore thinks it's free recycle the app pool. In some cases we've been uploading a new version while the background threads are still running. In any case, a very bad architecture.